# Difference between calling a python method and directly calling a celery task?

Tags: python, celery

Consider the following case:

```python
# tasks.py
@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def add_normal(x, y):
    return x + y
```

```python
# test.py
from tasks import add, add_normal
add(1, 2)
add_normal(1, 2)
```

Will this `add(1,2)` call be any different if the the add method is not turned into a celery task (`add_normal(1, 2)`)?

According to celery's doc [Calling Tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/next-steps.html#calling-tasks):

> Applying the task directly will execute the task in the current process, so that no message is sent:

but will the task be submitted to the broker if it fails and thus get re-tried later?

Is there any documents that give clearer explanation? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are same. If you want to send the method to task queue, you need to use `apply_async` or `delay` methods of the decorated object.

Comment: Emmm, just browsing the doc, how about this [Serializers](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#serializers) rule? Because not every python class instance can be pickled, will that be a concern if an object is passed to `addl()` when directly invoked?

Comment: from a quick glance at the [code](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/app/task.py) it seems that no, the inputs are not serialised when the task is directly invoked.